# SQL Query To Select From Either Or 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, database-schema

Am building a document manager, where a file can belong to many folders(When copied action is being performed from front-end) and a folder can belong to many file likewise, also to keep in mind a file and folder can belong to another folder.With that design i opted for a many to many relationship as that makes a lot of sense. I have three tables folders,files,file_folder where the file_folder is the pivot table.

My Simple DB Schema is defined below :

**files:**

`file_id | name
1       | document.docx`

**folders:**

`folder_id | name
1         | root
2         | images`

**file_folder:**

`file_id | folder_id | phash
NULL    | 2         | 1
1       | NULL      | 1`

Now the problem is, i have been trying to write a join query that returns a list of both files and folders if they share the same folder,below are the list of queries i have tried but none has been able to return the desired result.

I pretty much want my result this way:

`file_id | folder_id | name 
1       | NULL      | document.docx
NULL    | 2         | images`

`SELECT * FROM 
folders dir
JOIN file_folder dir_file
ON dir_file.dir_id = dir.dir_id
JOIN files file
ON dir_file.file_id = file.file_id
WHERE dir_file.dir_id = 1 ORDER BY dir_file.created_at`

`SELECT * FROM 
folders dir,files file
JOIN file_folder dir_file
ON (dir_file.file_id = file.file_id OR dir_file.dir_id = dir.dir_id)
WHERE dir_file.dir_id = 1 ORDER BY dir_file.created_at`

I know am just missing something out, that i can't figure out yet. Or maybe am just getting the DB Schema totally wrong. I really don't want to put files and folder on the same table and reference phash(parent folder), this will work but copying a folder with files into another one would just only copy the folder and not the files inside of it, as i will have to duplicate all the sub folders and files to make that happen, which is very bad. I will appreciate if i can get a solution to this

**EDITED:**

Below works fine for me now!

`SELECT * FROM folders dir 
LEFT JOIN file_folder dir_file 
ON dir_file.dir_id = dir.dir_id 
LEFT JOIN files file
ON dir_file.file_id = file.file_id 
WHERE dir_file.phash = 1 ORDER BY dir_file.created_at`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due the fact you have not always match between the tables  you should use left join

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM folders dir
  LEFT JOIN file_folder dir_file ON dir_file.dir_id = dir.dir_id and dir_file.phash = 1
  LEFT JOIN files file ON dir_file.file_id = file.file_id
  ORDER BY dir_file.created_at
```

And in left join move the where condition in On clause (otherwise work as a inner join )

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer actually pointed me into the right direction. Look at my question above for edited correct version.

Comment: @thanks  .. answer  update with phash  .. in condition